# JQuery Alphabetic navigation popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to implement a square alphabetic navigation popup similar to the one used to navigate an alphabetic list of contacts on linkedin but I am not sure where to start as I am new to JQuery. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: A link to an example of what you are trying to achieve would be awesome

Comment: if you have a linkedin account. http://www.linkedin.com/connections?trk=hb_tab_connections. There is a alphabetic popup for traversing the directory. I'm checking out listnav to see if I can make use of that but I'm very new to any web development so it is quite slow going for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ListNav plugin](http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx).

You can see some demos here:

http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx